# Unit test with Jest fails when I run it with loopback-remote-routing

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

Following the loopback-remote-routing syntax, I have included mixins object in the persisted model json file as follows:

```
"mixins": {
"RemoteRouting": {
"only": []
}
}
```

And, inside that array, I have listed my shared methods. But, the test fails leaving an error

> "Model  uses unknown mixin RemoteRouting"

I have fixed this issue in the remote-routing.js file by adding an else-if condition. But then, when I run the test, it leaves the error that

> "Unhandled error for request GET <endpoint_path>: Error: Shared class "<model_name>" has no method handling GET <endpoint_path>"

Please let me know how to fix this. Any help is appreciated.